# Slow-increasing function between 0 and 1

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a function that increases slowly at first and then moderately so, between 0 and 1, for x starting from 1 with no fixed upper limit. Something like the chart below. It would be great to be able to control the slope.

[image]

Comment: Take the log of your function. If it looks like a straight line, exponential would be a good fit. If it looks like the log function (increasing monotonically, but growth slowing down), polynomial would be a better fit. See discussion on exponential and polynomial below.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the family $f_n(x) = x^n$ which always is 0 at 0 and 1 at 1... If you have no fixed upper limit, try $f_n(x) = Ax^n$ for another slope-control parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at $f(x) = \exp(\alpha x) - 1$ for $\alpha > 0$ and use $\alpha$ to control the slope.

Of course $f_n(x) = x^n$ is also a great choice as the previous poster suggested.

I would suggest constraining the problem a bit more to help find the right family of functions to fit your data.

Comment: May be useful for OP to note that the first function you mentioned is an [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) while the second one is [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial). Both are commonly used to fit to data.